# Memory usage growing when using ffmpeg. Is this expected?

Tags: memory, ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg` record a video from a webcam, but the memory usage is very high, and keeps increasing  with video length.

For example, I use an embedded device with 64 MB of RAM, and when I recorded a 30 minute video, I was left with 2MB of RAM in the last minutes of the recording.

I used `valgrind` to check for memory leaks, but I only found a 24 byte leak when  the program finishes. Is this memory consumption expected for `ffmpeg`?

This is the `ffmpeg` command I used:

`ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -t 00:00:10 -i /dev/video0 out.mpg`